# Spark - Rdd transformation inside another transformation

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, rdd

I was trying to transform an RDD inside another transformation. Since, RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver I collected the 2nd RDD and tried to apply the transformation on it inside the other transformation like below

```
val name_match = first_names.map(y => (y, first_names_collection.value.filter(z => soundex.difference(z, y) == 4 )   ))
```

The above code is throwing the following exception

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.ApplicationAttemptNotFoundException): Application attempt appattempt_1468905506642_46091_000001 doesn't exist in ApplicationMasterService cache.
```

Here, the size of first_names_collection is more than 10 GB. Would that be causing this problem? Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: `first_names.cartesian.filter((x,y)  => soundex.difference(x,y) == 4).aggregateByKey({(xs,e) => e::xs}, {(xs,ys) => xs::ys}).` Or something like that. Not tested, and the compiler will probably need some help with explicit types to get it to compile.

Comment: Also, 10Gb of first names? Assuming they're the first names of people that's one heck of a lot of different names. "Nowt stranger than folk"

Comment: Oops, I missed passing the zero `List[String]()` to `aggregateByKey`. and didn't spot it within the 5 mins...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to calculate a difference function between each element of `name_match` and each element of `first_names_collection` and find pairs with a difference of 4.

Typically performing pair-wise calculations on two RDDs is done by enumerating all pairs using `cartesian` first. Your solution would look something like:

```
first_name.cartesian(first_names_collection)                     // generate all pairs
  .filter{case (lhs, rhs) => soundex.difference(lhs, rhs) == 4}
  .groupByKey
```

Comment: It is working but it is taking forever since the size of first_names_collection is more than 7 GB and it has more than 15 million first names.

Comment: Ouch, yea `cartesian` is expensive, `O(N*M)` for RDDs of size `N` and `M`. Twitter did some research on optimizing pairwise similarity, I haven't dug into it but the algorithm they developed is called DIMSUM, article here: https://databricks.com/blog/2014/10/20/efficient-similarity-algorithm-now-in-spark-twitter.html. It doesn't exactly fit your problem though, since you want to find pairs with an exact similarity of 4. Besides system optimizations (executor memory sizes, etc) you could try a sampled method, or split the giant operation into smaller chunks.